# Can lookout (Outlook plugin) work on windows 7 and office 2007

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2007, lookout

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Lookout on Windows 7 seems to always crash outlook when indexing](https://superuser.com/questions/398836/lookout-on-windows-7-seems-to-always-crash-outlook-when-indexing)

I am trying to install lookout (outlook search plugin) on Office 2007 and windows 7.  I already have it working on office 2007 but on XP.  WHen i try doing the same install on Windows 7 I get the error:

[image]

**I can't write some of my program files because they are in use.  Please stop Outlook and Retry and then i can continue**

I get this error even if outlook is not running.

Has anyone gotten lookout outlook plugin to work on Windows 7 and Outlook 2007

Comment: Try running the setup with the "run as administrator" otherwise contact company that develops said program.

Comment: @Ramhound - what do you mean run the setup with the "run as administrator" mean?  I am a local admin on the box

Comment: @Ramhound is probably right; see: [What is 'Run as Administrator' in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/235444/what-is-run-as-administrator-in-windows-7).

Comment: @Ramhound - you are correct. . if you move your comment to an answer, i will accept it.

Answer (score 2):

Outlook 2007 and later comes with its own search indexing feature, integrated with Desktop Search.  I believe this is actually derived from Lookout, even.

Comment: True, but the built in search feature takes roughly 100 times as long to search, so people with large inboxes prefer Lookout.