# Lookout on Windows 7 seems to always crash outlook when indexing

Tags: windows-7, microsoft-outlook, lookout

I installed lookout (outlook plugin) in outlook 2007 on windows XP and it works fine.  I am now trying to do the same thing on WINdows 7 ([using this lin](http://www.belshe.com/2007/12/06/how-to-install-lookout-on-outlook-2007/)k) but it immediately crashes outlook when it starts indexing.

Here is a screenshot of the crash that i see:

[image]

Does anyone know how to get lookout to work on windows 7 and outlook 2007?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can lookout (Outlook plugin) work on windows 7 and office 2007](http://superuser.com/questions/398525/can-lookout-outlook-plugin-work-on-windows-7-and-office-2007)

Comment: Stop trying to use out-dated and un-supported software, and use the built-in functionality instead.

Comment: @Iszi - i would be happy to do so but i can't find any software that is as good as lookout . . feel free to challenge me on that

Comment: @leora In my experience, the built-in search indexer for Outlook (which is integrated with Windows Desktop Search) is just as good as Lookout ever was.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like someone added a comment to the link above.  TO get it to work on Windows 7, you need to disable outlook search and then lower the "aggressiveness" chart on lookout and it will not crash anymore.

To avoid error "Outlook 2007 has stopped working", lower the amount of resources used in  Lookout Options → Advanced → Indexer Aggressiveness.

Comment: This is more of a workaround then a fix.  Lookout seems like a peice of crap software.  Eset's outlook add-on has no problem.

Comment: @Ramhound - i am not sure what you mean by "seems like a piece of crap software".  have you used it?  it works beautifully . . what is Eset addin ??

Answer (score 2):

See VLAD link below, which worked for me.

Actually, Lookout worked for me ok with this small change (http://www.belshe.com/2007/12/06/how-to-install-lookout-on-outlook-2007/) using the CMD rename hash but then an update was installed for Outlook 2007 on Win7 and Lookout started to crash.

I tried the CMD rename thing again, and Lookout would open, but would crash on indexing.

I am happy I found the patched dll files on Vlad's website.  Using them on Lookout 1.20 works for me, like a dream.  And also saves messing with the CMD prompt.

https://web.archive.org/web/*/http://vlad.bailescu.ro/articles/2008/07/01/outlook-2007-vista-spam-protection-and-lightning-fast-search/

Happy indexing!