# Permissions warning when running an .exe flash file in Windows 7

Tags: windows-7, permissions, administrator

I have a flash .exe file generated from adobe_captivate5.5. I tried to run that file in windows 7, but I get this error:
[image]
My account has administrative privilege. If I right click and select `Run as administrator`, it runs fine. But I need it to run without doing that. Why is it asking for administrative privileges although I have administrator permission? how to avoid this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why do I need to run commands as administrator if my account is member of administrator group?](http://superuser.com/questions/107358/why-do-i-need-to-run-commands-as-administrator-if-my-account-is-member-of-admini) also see [What is 'Run as Administrator' in Windows 7?](http://superuser.com/questions/235444/what-is-run-as-administrator-in-windows-7?rq=1)

Comment: Sounds like your system wide settings on Flash are set to require these privileges.  You would have to adjust the system wide settings using the Flash control panel applet.